# spring integration multiple stored procedure enricher pattern

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to spring integration. I have very specific requirement.

1. I have two Database to fetch.
2. Created two SP.
3. I have to get the data calling their respective stored procedure and create a JAXB object to make webservice call.

I am able to call one SP but not able to call 2nd SP. I think I can use enricher pattern but dont know how to configure.

Please help.

Comment: Please, rephrase the question some how. It isn't clear what you would like to achieve and why Reference Manual isn't enough for you: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#content-enricher

Comment: As I said I have two database to execute to get one Domain object information. Example Customer order details stored in one db and address stored in another db. My first question how can I execute two SPs. 2nd How can merge them into one Customer object

Comment: And restating the problem, there, doesn't make it any clearer what you're trying to do.  "how can I execute two SPs" is incredibly broad....

Comment: I have two stored procedures to execute(from different database) through spring integration. Each stored procedure returns multiple results. Using multiple rowmapper for each stored procedure, I am able to create pojo objects. Now what I have to do is merge them and create a single domain object.  I used stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter to call one Stored procedure but not able to make 2nd stored procedure call.

Answer (score 0):

Well, trying to answer to your so broad question I only may suggest:

1. Configure `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>` to call first SP
2. Configure `<int:enricher>` with a `request-channel` for sub-flow to call the second SP similar way like a previous one
3. with this `<int:enricher>` you will be able to store additional info in some your `Customer` model property (which is `payload`) or `headers`
4. And so on until WS call.

Everything rest you can find in the Spring Integration Reference Manual and [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) project.

**UPDATE**

> I still need help.

Since it looks like you still don't understand Spring Integration principles properly, I'd suggest you to have one `<service-activator>` and call both stored procedures in custom code using Spring JDBC directly.

Eventually with an experience you will be able to refactor it really to separate components with the `<enricher>` on board.

OTOH your scenario recalls me [Scatter-Gather](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather) pattern.

Comment: I still need help.

Comment: I still need help.  I created one gateway named inputchannel. created two stored-proc-outbound-gatway, both request-channel is inputchannel but their reply-channel(s) are spchanel1 and spchannel2. At a time only one SP executes. I need help on how to glue both SPs out channel using enricher. Please help.

Comment: See an UPDATe in my answer.